# Axios post request: Data after transformation must be a string, an ArrayBuffer, a Buffer, or a Stream

Tags: node.js, axios

```
const _axios = new Axios({})

await _axios.post(`${ENDPOINT}/raw-houses/should-scrape`, {
  scraper: 'a',
  detail_url: 'b',
  should_not_scrape_reason: 'c'
}, {
  headers: {
    'X-Api-Token': API_TOKEN,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
```

Gives the error:

```json
{
  "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
  "config": {
    "data": {},
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "User-Agent": "axios/1.4.0",
      "X-Api-Token": "TOKEN"
    },
    "method": "post",
    "url": "http://rentbird.local/api/scrapers/raw-houses/should-scrape"
  },
  "message": "Data after transformation must be a string, an ArrayBuffer, a Buffer, or a Stream",
  "name": "AxiosError",
  "stack": "AxiosError: Data after transformation must be a string, an ArrayBuffer, a Buffer, or a Stream\n    at dispatchHttpRequest (/Users/dirk/projects/_rentbird/scrapers/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:304:23)\n    at /Users/dirk/projects/_rentbird/scrapers/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:143:5\n    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    at wrapAsync (/Users/dirk/projects/_rentbird/scrapers/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:123:10)\n    at http (/Users/dirk/projects/_rentbird/scrapers/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:149:10)\n    at Axios.dispatchRequest (/Users/dirk/projects/_rentbird/scrapers/node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:51:10)\n    at Axios.request (/Users/dirk/projects/_rentbird/scrapers/node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:148:33)\n    at Axios.httpMethod [as post] (/Users/dirk/projects/_rentbird/scrapers/node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:187:19)\n    at Object.setShouldNotScrapeHouse (/Core/ScraperApi.ts:60:22)\n    at WoonmatchWestfriesland.parseHouseBlock (/Scrapers/ScraperInstance.ts:87:30)",
 
 "status": null
}
```

Why????

In Postman it works perfectly.
[image]

Comment: Which version of Axios?

Answer (score 1):

Using `JSON.stringify()` seems to work. Which is very strange because it goes directly against the Axios documentation.

Comment: yes. sending stringified json in body (with axios) does the trick.